# Tried to retrieve some pictures from database but failed to show images

Tags: java, android

This was my adapter view but glide failed to bring image.i tried running it but does not show pictures

```
public class myadapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Store, myadapter.myviewholder>{

    public myadapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Store> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull Store model) {
        holder.feed_news.setText(model.getNewstxt());
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(model.getFeedpic()).into(holder.feed_pic);
        Glide.with(holder.profile_pic.getContext()).load(model.getProfilepic()).into(holder.profile_pic);


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feed_item,parent,false);
        return new myviewholder(view);
    }
      class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ShapeableImageView profile_pic;
        ImageView feed_pic;
        TextView feed_news;
        public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            feed_news =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.feed_news);
            feed_pic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.feed_pic);
            profile_pic = (ShapeableImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);

        }
    }
}
```

And am looking for some solution on

```java
Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(model.getFeedpic()).into(holder.feed_pic);
Glide.with(holder.profile_pic.getContext()).load(model.getProfilepic()).into(holder.profile_pic);
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to know what value of model.getFeedpic() or model.getProfilepic(). If value of that is name of image, it can not show, when using Glide. Maybe you can upload to firestorage first and then get the url from firestorage.

try this to upload the image [upload file to firabase storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files?hl=id)

and than add this code to get url of image from firestorage

```
StorageReference storageReference1 = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()+ "."+ GetFileExtension(FilePathUri));
    storageReference1.putFile(FilePathUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            storageReference1.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> { url = uri.toString(); }

        }
    });
```

So you can set the value of model.getFeedpic() or model.getProfilepic() is url from firestorage.

I hope can solve your problem, Thank you